# Access query speed differs

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access

I have a local access database and in it a query which takes values from a form to populate a drop down menu. The weird (to me) thing is that with most options this query is quick (blink of an eye), but with a few options it's very slow (>10 seconds).
What the query is does is a follows: It populates a dropdown menu to record animals seen at a specific sighting, but only those animals which have not been recorded at that specific sighting yet (to avoid duplicate entries).

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblAnimals.AnimalID, tblAnimals.Nickname, tblAnimals.Species
FROM tblSightings INNER JOIN (tblAnimals INNER JOIN tblAnimalsatSighting ON tblAnimals.AnimalID = tblAnimalsatSighting.AnimalID) ON tblSightings.SightingID = tblAnimalsatSighting.SightingID
WHERE (((tblAnimals.Species)=[form]![Species]) AND ((tblAnimals.CurrentGroup)=[form]![AnimalGroup2]) AND ((tblAnimals.[Dead?])=False) AND ((Exists (select tblAnimalsatSighting.AnimalID FROM tblAnimalsatSighting WHERE tblAnimals.AnimalID = tblAnimalsatSighting.AnimalID AND tblAnimalsatSighting.SightingID = [form]![SightingID]))=False));
```

It performs well for all groups of 2 of the 4 possible species, for 1 species it performs well for 4 of the 5 groups, but not for the last group, and for the last species it performs very slowly for both groups. Anybody an idea what can be the cause of this kind of behavior? Is it problems with the query? Or duplicate entries in the tables which can cause this? I don't think it's duplicates in the tables, I've checked that, and there are some, but they appear both for groups where there are problems and where there aren't. Could I re-write the query so it performs faster?

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing the joins at all. It looks like all the filtering relates to animal species and group and then the subquery checks for no sightings. In fact I think that's going to require a previous sighting somewhere for each animal for it it to even appear on the list and you probably don't want that. So just `FROM tblSightings WHERE ...`

Comment: I mean `FROM tblAnimals WHERE ...`

Comment: It indeed does exactly what you suspect (it requires a previous sighting), and indeed I don't want that. What you propose works perfectly, I guess I made life more difficult than it is! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in our comments above, you confirmed that the extra joins were not really need and were in fact going to limit the results to animal that had already had a sighting. Those joins would also likely contribute to a slowdown.

I know that Access probably added most of the parentheses automatically but I've removed them and converted the subquery to a `not exists` form that's a lot more readable.

```
SELECT tblAnimals.AnimalID, tblAnimals.Nickname, tblAnimals.Species
FROM tblAnimals
WHERE
        tblAnimals.Species = [form]![Species]
    AND tblAnimals.CurrentGroup = [form]![AnimalGroup2]
    AND tblAnimals.[Dead?] = False
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT tblAnimalsatSighting.AnimalID
        FROM tblAnimalsatSighting
        WHERE
                tblAnimals.AnimalID = tblAnimalsatSighting.AnimalID
            AND tblAnimalsatSighting.SightingID = [form]![SightingID]
    );
```